# jQuery hide elements when new element selected

Tags: jquery

I have a series of icons which when clicked reveal a small arrow and a list of products. I can get the arrow to display and the list to slide down but what I'd like to do is hide the currently visible list and arrow when another icon is clicked.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction please?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="stockist-block">
      <li class="stockist-icon" id="STORE1">
          <img src="icon1.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" />
        <div class="stockist-arrow"> 
            <img src="blue-arrow.jpg"/> 
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="stockist-icon" id="STOREONSTREET">
          <img src="icon2.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" />
        <div class="stockist-arrow"> 
            <img src="blue-arrow.jpg"/> 
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="stockist-icon" id="SHOPONCORNER">
          <img src="icon3.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" />
        <div class="stockist-arrow"> 
            <img src="blue-arrow.jpg"/> 
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="container"> 
    <div class="stockist-block-dropdown STORE1">
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stockist-block-dropdown STOREONSTREET">
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stockist-block-dropdown SHOPONCORNER">
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">product-title4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $ (".stockist-icon").on('click', function(){
        $(this).children('.stockist-arrow').css('visibility','visible');
        var elementid = $(this).attr("id");
        $("div." + elementid).stop().slideDown(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: a possible solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sdhm84c/)

Comment: This works. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can slideUp all other divs except current one using class selector of jquery. Here you can use `class` attribute with values starting as `STORE`, see below code

NOTE: jQuery has `.show()` and `.hide()` functions to show and hide html elements so no need to use `.css()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $ (".stockist-icon").on('click', function(){
        //$(this).children('.stockist-arrow').css('visibility','visible'); -- use .show()
        $(this).children('.stockist-arrow').show();
        var elementid = $(this).attr("id");
        var selector = "div.stockist-block-dropdown." + elementid;
        $("div.stockist-block-dropdown").not(selector).stop().slideUp(400); // slidup other divs
        $(selector).stop().slideDown(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I may have over simplified my html a little as the ID's and classes STORE1, STORE2 etc.. will likely be store names. I've rectified my original post to allow for this.

Comment: you can still make use of `stockist-block-dropdown` class attached to all divs, i hv updated my post, pls check

Comment: happy to help you :). you can accept this answer if find useful